# Development pipe line integration between multiple java projects with jenkins and artifactory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory

I have the following stack:

- 3 java project
- maven
- Jenkins
- Artifactory (jfrog)
- git

In order to simplify let's call each of the project as A B C.
Each of them has their own CI.
There is a pipe line of A+B that are tight together, we first build A if it passes we run B on top of the artifacts of A. 
The problem is that I want to have a pipeline of C, that will run on the most latest artifact of A and B but with one limitation, we need to make sure there is a pipeline that passed successfully for A+B.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you need to achieve following:

A --> Build --> Success --> latest

B --> Build --> depends on A --> Success --> latest

C --> Build --> depends on latest of A and B --> Success

Project A:

The artifacts of A will be deployed only when A is success. there is an artifactory api that will get the latest artifacts or you can use a aql or the jenkins plugin of artifactory for the same.

Project B:

The CI of  B would depend on A so it will trigger if there is any latest artifacts of A assuming you always need latest of A. There is an option in artifactory plugin of jenkins where it will download the latest of A then start building B if success then it will deploy B artifacts.

Project C:

The similar plugin or aql or api can be used to download the latest artifacts from A and B then build C. If C is success artifacts would be deployed to artifactory for C.

Also since you are using mvn you can create a repo mvn type configure the java pom.xml to this remote repo in artifactory to fetch the dependencies while building